# indentation of a swift multiline string

Tags: swift, multilinestring

For the following multi-line string:

```
    jsContext.evaluateScript(
            """
            var console = {
                log: function(data) { __swift_log(data); }
            };
            """)
```

A compilation error is reported:

```
error: repl.swift:37:9: error: insufficient indentation of next 2 lines in multi-line string literal
        log: function(data) { __swift_log(data); }
        ^

repl.swift:39:9: note: should match space here
                """)
        ^

repl.swift:37:9: note: change indentation of these lines to match closing delimiter
        log: function(data) { __swift_log(data); }
```

I tried all sorts of things the only one that works is having the whole thing *flush* !!

```
"""
var console = {
log: function(data) { __swift_log(data); }
};
""")
```

[image]

That is an undesirable way to embed a heredoc / multi-line string. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I can't replicate this in Xcode nor at the swift repl command line. Can you provide a complete test case?

Comment: I am running this in the `repl` on 5.2.2.    What are you looking for wrt `test case` - given `xcode` projects are a pretty big deal to put together?